# how to get a field of #root.args[0] in SpEL in @CacheEvict#key

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-el

```java
@Service
public class UserService {
    private final User[] database = new User[]{new User(0, "foo")};
    @Cacheable(cacheNames = "springboot:demo:cache", key = "#root.args[0]")
    public User query(Integer id) {
        return database[0];
    }

    @CacheEvict(cacheNames = "springboot:demo:cache", key = "#root.args[0].id")
    public void update(User user) {
        database[0] = user;
    }
}
```

```java
@Data
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
public class User implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = -1760350679406802739L;
    Integer id;
    String name;
}
```

after method `update` was invoked, `springboot:demo:cache:{id}` generated from method `query` still exists in cache(Redis). What should I do to evict it accurately? Thanks a lot.

Comment: this code is fine and runs as configured. You can also the method argument names for the keys. like @Cacheable(cacheNames = "springboot:demo:cache", key = "#id") and     @CacheEvict(cacheNames = "springboot:demo:cache", key = "#user.id)

Comment: If you feel it doesn't work, provide more details like where and how you are testing this. Spring and Redis versions. What is that you expect to happen?

Comment: @GSSwain Thanks for your answer. I double-checked my demo, and it is indeed a problem with my own writing.